# Prime Number Error

Tags: java, loops

I was wondering what the issue was with my prime number code.
I feel it might have to do with the arrangement of my repetition but I am not sure. The idea was as a prime number can only be divisible evenly by 1 and itself that I would use f_check to check this. It only out puts numbers 2 and 3. Where did I go wrong?

```
int [] f_numb;
double f_pri;
int f_check = 0;

f_numb = new int [101];

for (int cnto = 2; cnto<=100; cnto++) {

    f_numb [cnto] = cnto;

    for( int cnt=100; cnt>=1; cnt--) {
        f_pri = f_numb [cnto]%cnt;
        if (f_pri==0) {
             f_check=f_check+1;
        }
    }

    if (f_check == 2) {
        System.out.println(f_numb [cnto]);
        f_check = 0;

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the complete code and fix the formatting?  Also, the Java variable naming convention is to use camel case, e.g. `fCheck` instead of `f_check`.

Comment: Hey Tim, the only other code is the importing and public class/static void code. And sorry for the variable mishap but does camel case change the outcome at all?

Comment: Hey Max, I'm not quite understanding the problem you raise. Would you mind showing me where the error is that causes f_pri to stay at 2?

Comment: inside first for loop add `f_check=0`

Comment: Thank you guys I see it now :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when cnto is 4? You will increment f_check when cnt is 4, 2, and 1, totaling 3. Since f_check doesn't equal 2 it will miss your if statement and for the rest of your outer for loop it will never reset to zero and just keep incrementing f_check when a factor of a number is found.

Comment: Thank you Nick! Now I see it, I missed a f_check = 0 statement after the if statement. So as you were saying f_check never gets reset at 4. Thank you so much it works now. Cheers dude.